# The image from my website doesn't show on google image search

Tags: php, html, image, google-search

I have some images set on my website made with cakephp2. The problem is that the website is released to the public, yet
the images won't show up on Google image search even when I search the name of the image.

Is it related to Lazy Load or something that is related to the description of alt originally?
I thought the alt tag was the cause, so I removed it from the img tag, but the problem doesn't solve. All I want to do is to make the image available when searched be the google image search. I searched for a solution but unable to find a solution.Some sample or hint would be a great help! I would love to hear from you!

```
<img src="<?=IMAGE_DIR?>billy_joe.gif" data-original="<?=$family_image?>" alt="billy joe"  >
↓
<img src="<?=IMAGE_DIR?>billy_joe.gif" data-original="<?=$$family_image?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Was the site indexed by Google at all? Is it coming up when searching for a phrase that is unique to your site? If not, make sure to list the site: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url
Just FYI, indexing by any search engine could take some time. Changes you are making to your site won't be triggering a new indexing right away.

You should definitely bring back the 'alt' tag by the way.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I have an question. Why would I need to bring back the alt tag?

Comment: Firstly, the ALT attribute is necessary to keep your code up to code (its correct HTML) :)
The browser is loading the HTML portion first, and then the CSS, JS, images etc... If for some reason your internet connection is not strong enough or the image is missing then the ALT text will be shown instead.

Secondly, search engine will index your image and will make a relationship to these keywords in the ALT attribute; so  whenever you search for that ALT attribute phrase, your image will potentially come up.